# Alternative proof of Noether Normalization Lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

On Mumford's Red Book (end of section 7 of chapter 2, pg 126, 127), there is an alternative proof of Noether's Normalization Lemma that goes like this:

For an affine variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, we consider $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n_k$ and embed $\mathbb{A}^n_k\subset\mathbb{P}^n_k$ as the complement of the hyperplane $X_0=0$. Then we consider $\overline{X}$, the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ and take $L$, a maximal linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n_k\setminus \mathbb{A}^n_k$.

First question: Why there exists such a maximal subspace?

Let $l_0=X_0$, $l_1,\dots,l_r$ be the generators of $L$ and set $W_i=\text{Spec }k[\frac{x_0}{l_i},\dots,1,\dots,\frac{x_n}{l_i}]$, an open affine subset of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$.

Now, define $\pi_1:\mathbb{P}^n_k\setminus L\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^r_k$, such that $\pi^{-1}(V_i)=W_i$ and $\pi_1^{*}(\frac{y_k}{y_i})=\frac{l_k}{l_i}$, where $V_i=\text{Spec }k[\frac{y_0}{y_i},\dots,\frac{y_r}{y_i}]$ are the affine opens of $\mathbb{P}^r_k$. By a previous lemma of Mumford, $\pi=\pi_1 |Z$ is a finite morphism.

Then he claims that $\pi^{-1}(V_0)=X$.

Second question: why?

And, finally, $\pi'=\pi|X:X\rightarrow V_0=\mathbb{A}^r_k$ is finite and surjective: it is finite because it is the restriction of a finite morphism, but...

Third question: why is $\pi'$ surjective?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I haven't thought through all the details. The hyperplane exists just because it can fit in the complement by dimension arguments. Surjectivity follows because the map is closed, the space is irreducible (you can assume this), and they have the same dimension. So, the image has the same dimension as the domain (by finiteness), and so the same dimension as the codimain, is irreducible and closed, so must be the full thing

Comment: Thanks. I will follow your hints.